# How can I run a function when an expression goes out-of-scope?

Tags: clojure, garbage-collection

I've got an expression that has a side-effect:

```
(database-reference "sites" "stackoverflow" "users")
```

This creates a reference that must be cleaned-up.  Functionally, I need to

```
(let [ref (database-reference ...)]
  (do-things-to ref)
  (.close ref)
```

but specifying that `let` form all the time won't be very intuitive for other programmers (my users).  It's also inappropriate to require using a macro all the time.

I'd like to call `.close` automatically when `ref` goes out-of-scope.  I can implement a protocol for all `database-reference`s, but I can't find a protocol that's appropriate.  My instinct is to say something like:

```
(deftype DatabaseReference [stuff]
  clojure.lang.IDispose
  (dispose [this] (.close this))
```

but `clojure.lang.IDispose` does not exist, of course.

Comment: `with-open` should do the job

Comment: @Andre `with-open` is effectively the macro case I need to avoid.

Comment: removed the answer so it's visible as not having an answer

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The bound value is not supposed to know anything about what's it bound to, so it can be passed around freely. Imagine anyone fetching the reference and putting it ouside, e. g. into an `atom`. A reference then goes out fo scope and is (assuming what you're asking for was possible) closed, so a reference stored in an atom would no longer be usable.